# Powershell ArrayList remove item with special characters

Tags: powershell, arraylist, special-characters

I do this

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$packageList = (Get-ChildItem "\\path-to-files" -Filter *.zip )
Write-Host $packageList
$packageList.Remove("ABC_Export-Cars.zip")
Write-Host $packageList
```

Remove doesn't work with this kind of item nevertheless it's in the array.  With a simple array e.g. containing "A","B","C" it works. Are "_" or "-" characters which need a special processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your ArrayList contains a collection of FileInfo objects returned by `Get-ChildItem`. So none of those items match the string you're trying to remove. Obviously when you use a collection of strings (a,b,c) then you can match a string for removal.

You probably just want the names of the files in your ArrayList, in which case do this:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$packageList = (Get-ChildItem "\\path-to-files" -Filter *.zip).name
```

The `.Remove` operation then should work for a specified file name.

Answer (score 3):

**[Mark Wragg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51426684/45375) explains the problem with your attempt well and offers an effective alternative based on names only.**

If you had indeed wanted to collect the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances that `Get-ChildItem` outputs in `$packageList` (rather than just their `.Name` property values), your `.Remove()`-based approach *couldn't* have worked, because you would have had to pass the *very same `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instance* that is already a part of the array list in order to successfully remove it.

The reason is that the `.Remove()` method uses *reference equality* to find list elements that are instances of [.NET *reference types*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (the only exception being *strings*, which are treated like *value types* in this context).
That is, the argument passsed to `.Remove()` must be the *very same object* in order to be found in the list (not another object that happens to represent the same thing).

Therefore, **it would have been easier to exclude the file named `ABC_Export-Cars.zip` file at the *source***:

```
$packageList = Get-ChildItem "\\path-to-files\*.zip" -Exclude ABC_Export-Cars.zip
```

Using the `-Exclude` parameter allows you to exclude the specific file name as part of the `Get-ChildItem` call; do note that the `*.zip` wildcard had to be made part of the (implied) `-Path` argument to make this work.

If excluding at the source is not an option, the **alternative is to use a - slow - *loop*** to remove the file-info object of interest:

```
$packageList = foreach ($file in $packageList) {
  if ($file.Name -ne 'ABC_Export-Cars.zip') {
     $_ # pass the object through
  }
}
```

Note that `$packageList` receives a newly created *array* (`[object[]]`) as a result, and that there's therefore no good reason to type `$packageList` as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` to begin with.

A more concise - and slightly faster - alternative is to use the **PSv4+ [`.Where()` collection-filtering method](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/)**:

```
$packageList = $packageList.Where({ $_.Name -ne 'ABC_Export-Cars.zip' })
```

In this case the output collection type is `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, though in most contexts it will behave like a regular array (or array list).

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Wragg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2796058/mark-wragg) has already answered your question. Just in case if you want to use `Remove` method, you can use the index of the required file to remove it. For example -

```
$packageList.Remove($packageList[n])
```

**where n = Index of the file you want to remove**

Comment: That works, but you can more simply use the `RemoveAt()` method, which accepts the index of the item to remove directly: `$packageList.RemoveAt(<n>)`